# MySQL inner join w/ alias

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, alias

So this is my table DENUNCIAS

```
id_denuncia, 
id_categoria, 
id_fecha, 
email_denunciante -- FK table usuarios, 
email_denunciado  -- FK table usuarios, 
descripcion, 
fecha
```

As you can see i have a double reference to the same table.

What i'm trying to do is select (inner join) 'usuarios.nombreCompleto' twice, once for 'email_denunciante' and the other for 'email_denunciado' . This is where i am so far:

```
select 
categorias.nombreCorto as 'Categoria', 
fechas.circuito as 'Fecha', 
usuarios.nombreCompleto as usuDenunciante, 
usuarios.nombreCompleto as usuDenunciado,
denuncias.descripcion as 'Detalle', 
denuncias.fecha as 'Enviada el'
from denuncias
inner join categorias on denuncias.id_categoria = categorias.id_categoria
inner join fechas on denuncias.id_fecha = fechas.id_fecha
inner join usuarios as usuDenunciante on denuncias.email_denunciante = usuarios.email
inner join usuarios as usuDenunciado on denuncias.email_denunciado = usuarios.email;
```

And this is the error i get:

```
Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'usuarios.nombreCompleto' in 'field list'
```

I'd tried several methods with negative results.

Since it's a sintaxis error, not logic, i decided not to translate the code.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: /offtopic/ the main reason everyone should code in English is that no one else can read their code if they have problems with it otherwise. I just can't read through all the Spanish to your real issue. And I'm not even a native English speaker.

Comment: I totally agree. But since my error was pure sintaxis not logic, i decided not to translate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create table alias, you must use then on your select list. `usuarios` must be `usuDenunciante` or `usuDenunciado`.

Try this:

```
select categorias.nombreCorto as 'Categoria', 
       fechas.circuito as 'Fecha', 
       usuDenunciante.nombreCompleto as usuDenunciante, 
       usuDenunciado.nombreCompleto as usuDenunciado,
       denuncias.descripcion as 'Detalle', 
       denuncias.fecha as 'Enviada el'
  from denuncias
          inner join categorias 
                  on denuncias.id_categoria =  categorias.id_categoria
          inner join fechas 
                  on denuncias.id_fecha = fechas.id_fecha
          inner join usuarios as usuDenunciante 
                  on denuncias.email_denunciante = usuDenunciante.email
          inner join usuarios as usuDenunciado 
                  on denuncias.email_denunciado = usuDenunciado.email;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that your usarious table really do contain the nombreCompleto column. If this is correct, I think the problem is, that you reference the usarious table directly instead of using the aliases you have made. Because you access that table twice, you need to specify which alias you mean to SELECT from.

Fx:

```
SELECT categorias.nombreCorto as 'Categoria',
fechas.circuito as 'Fecha',
usuDenunciante.nombreCompleto.as usuDenunciante,
usuDenunciado.nombreCompleto as usuDenunciado,
denuncias.descripcion as 'Detalle',
denuncias.fecha as 'Enviada el'
from denuncias inner join categorias on denuncias.id_categoria = categorias.id_categoria
inner join fechas on denuncias.id_fecha = fechas.id_fecha
inner join usuarios as usuDenunciante on denuncias.email_denunciante = usuarios.email
inner join usuarios as usuDenunciado on denuncias.email_denunciado = usuarios.email;
```